# Traefik V2.0 with Letsencrypt is unable to generate a certificate for the domains

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm testing with Whoami and get an issue generating the certificates.

No certificate is generated into the acme.json file and the sites are using a default certificate from Traefik that is considered as invalid by the navigators.

Here is the error:

```
traefik         | time="2019-10-14T21:16:15Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"inner-whoami.mysite.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [inner-whoami.mysite.com]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[inner-whoami.mysite.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from https://inner-whoami.mysite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [51.75.207.100]: \"Hostname: xxxxxxxxxx\\nIP: 127.0.0.1\\nIP: 172.18.0.2\\nRemoteAddr: 172.18.0.3:55692\\nGET /.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxx\", url: \n" rule="Host(`inner-whoami.mysite.com`)" routerName=inner-whoami-secured providerName=myhttpchallenge.acme
traefik         | time="2019-10-14T21:16:17Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Unable to deactivate the authorization: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file. Evrything is inside. As you can see, this is a test for preparing further deployement. Not an actual production file.I need to solve this issue before being able to use Traefik server wide...

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
    # Allow the use of traefik in other docker-compose.yml files
    traefik:
        external: true

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      # Only for development environment
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      # Get Docker as the provider
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      # Avoid that all containers are exposed
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      # Settle the ports for the entry points
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443"
      # Settle the autentification method to http challenge
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web-secure"
      # Uncomment this to get a fake certificate when testing
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      # Settle letsencrypt as the certificate provider
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.email=me@mail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - "traefik"
    volumes:
      # Store certificates in ./letsencrypt/acme.json
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      # Connect to Doker socket
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  inner-whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "inner-whoami"
    networks:
      - "traefik"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami.rule=Host(`inner-whoami.mysite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami-secured.rule=Host(`inner-whoami.mysite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.inner-whoami-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to change the entry point for http challenge from `web-secure` to `web`, i.e.:

`- "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"`

Or use [TLS Challenge](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/) instead:

`- "--certificatesresolvers.myhttpchallenge.acme.tlschallenge=true"`

Answer (score 2):

Did you examine the json in the link of the second line your error output?

> `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/xxxxxxxxxx`

This link contains more info about the challenge not passing. If it complains about an A record not being found I might have a solution. In my case I needed to add an MX record to my DNS settings for my domain. Otherwise some DNS servers wouldn't pick it up. I tested this with `dig sub.mydomain.com @8.8.8.8` which gave a SERVFAIL without the MX record.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with your real url instead of mysite.com?

Comment: ok, write-access for docker at - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt" ?

Comment: Docker created the folder so I guess yes. It was on root rw. I tried to chown it to myuser. It did not change the behavior.